# Does keeping underflowed nodes unbalance the R-tree?

Tags: trees, balanced-search-trees

When deleting nodes from an R-tree, if a branch underflows, then it's meant to be dissolved and its children are meant to be reinserted into the tree. But most R-tree implementations that I've seen just keep the node until it's completely empty. Does this lead to unbalanced R-trees?